# Unable to connect application on localhost after docker deploymnet is successful

Tags: spring-boot, docker, dockerfile, war

**I am trying to deploy a spring boot war file on docker container**

This is my docker file:

```
FROM tomcat:alpine

RUN wget -O /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ROOT.war -U admin:Learning http://localhost:8082/artifactory/demoArtifactory/com/demo/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war

EXPOSE 8080

CMD ["catalina.sh", "run"]
```

[image]

[image]

I am unable to connect to localhost:7000

**UPDATE:**
This is the docker run command:

> docker run -it --name demo-application -d -p 8080:8080
> hmt/demo-application:49

```
"PortBindings": {
                "8080/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "",
                        "HostPort": "8080"
                    }
                ]
            }
```

Now my tomcat is up on localhost:8080 but I am unable to access my application

**UPDATE:**

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Comment: Please favor text to images.

Comment: Can you show the snippet of your demoApplication main class ?

Comment: @iron_man I have added the snippet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.You need to extend SpringBootServletInitializer.Spring Boot Servlet Initializer class file allows you to configure the application when it is launched by using Servlet Container
Reference: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring_boot/spring_boot_tomcat_deployment.htm

2.Rename your war file from ROOT.war to something like sample.war .ROOT default app is usually Tomcat Manager

Answer (score 3):

Look at your port information :
The port `9100` of the container is published on the port `7000` on the host.
But look at your log application : it is deployed on `8080` (and not on `9100`).
What you want is publishing the container port `8080` on the `7000` port of the host such as :

```
docker run -p 7000:8080 foo-image
```

Comment: My tomcat server is up on 8080 but I am still not able to access my application

Comment: @HMT It looks ok now. Please inspect container logs to understand. I edited.

Comment: Yes I did that .There is no such information in logs

Comment: Hmmm.  But what is your error ? Can you remove the tomcat ROOT app folder before the wget statement ? `RUN rm -rf /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ROOT`